# betting problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

suppose A have got 1 Rs and B have got 1000 rs ,both bet the money starting from  1-1,A wins so now he have 2 rs,both bet 2-2 rs,again A wins, how many times does A have to win to take all the money from B?

Comment: Can you edit into your question what you have tried yourself?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your question is not complete. What happens 3rd time? Do they bet 3 rupees each or 4 rupees each? Also what happens when B has less money left than A? Do they start betting as per money left with B?

Comment: yes each time they bet the same amount only  A wins,